# Grouping multiple same node contents in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm creating and XSLT file to display some data from an XML file as CSV.
I'm stuck on a particular aspect because I can't find many online examples with similar xml structure.

Given this hypothetical XML:

```
<collection>
 <book>
  <author> author1name </author>
  <author> author2name </author>
  <title> booktitle </title>
 </book>
 <book>
  <author> authorname </author>
  <title> booktitle </title>
 </book>
</collection>
```

And the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
author,title

<xsl:for-each select="//book">
<xsl:value-of select="concat

(author,',',title',','&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives an output of

```
author, title
author1name, booktitle
authorname, booktitle
```

Note that there is no author2 included in the output. This is a big loss of data.
I've tried to use a nested for loop to cycle through all authors but I've hit too many errors to count.

Can someone suggest a method to produce an output of

```
author1name;author2name, booktitle
```

for book one? (where the two authors are separated by semicolon)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concat() is a *string* function; you cannot apply it to *node-sets*. Try instead:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>author,title&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="collection/book">
        <xsl:for-each select="author">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create a template that matches `author` where you simply output the name, and semi-colon preceding it if it is not the first author

```
<xsl:template match="author">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">;</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Then, to output each book, rather than putting `author` in the concat statement, use `xsl:apply-templates` instead

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="author" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat(',', title,'&#xA;')"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

   <xsl:template match="collection">
       <xsl:text>author,title</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="book">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="author"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(',', title,'&#xA;')"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="author">
      <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">;</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: As an aside, in the future, if you were able to use XSLT 2.0, you could make use of the `separator` attribute of the `xsl:value-of` operator to achieve the same result:

```
<xsl:value-of select="author" separator=";" />
```